# Disable competing language servers / code highlighters

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add a language server to handle completion / highlighting / etc. for a file.
As a basis for testing stuff I am using an example from Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-sample) and changed it to be active for any File. This language server highlights any word in all capital letters.

When opening a C++ File, I get the highlighting / completion of my language server and the default one for C++ (See image).

[image: Image: competing highlighters: 1: my extension, 2: other extension]

I would like to detect if some other extension / build in highlighter is active for a file and deactivate it for this workspace or the current file if it is impossible for the current workspace)

1. Is there a way to do this in a generic way where I do not have to know which extensions are highlighting code?
2. If no, is there a way to do this, if I know a set of extensions I want to deactivate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had enough time to try around a bit more and found that providing your own language for the same extension is enough.

In `package.json` I added an element in `contributes.languages` with `extensions` containing `.cpp` (since I am using cpp files for testing).

I also copied over some implementation code [from an example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/semantic-tokens-sample).

This suppressed the default highlighter and code completion for cpp files. Since i am only implementing a [semantic token provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide), I can see the default highlighting before my provider takes over. (I think this could be solved by adding a [syntax highlighter](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide), but this is already sufficient fo my preliminary testing)

I am not sure, how stable all of this would be as a plugin (I only tested in Extension Development Host mode)

Here an image of the results:
[image]